# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foreground' of undefined

Tags: jquery

This is my basic jquery plugin code and after applying this code i am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'foreground' of undefined

```
(function($){

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){

        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.default, options);

        $.fn.myPlugin.default = {
            foreground: "red",
            background: "green"
        };
    }

}(jQuery));
```

And here i am trying to access it using this plugin code

```
    $.fn.myPlugin.default.foreground = "blue";

    $(".testDemo").myPlugin();
```

Is there anyone who can help me out to resolve this problem ! please its a request

Comment: there is no css style property called foreground. Use style 'color' in place of foreground

Comment: Please add clarity to the questions. Explain what you want to achieve in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems in that code:

1. In one place you're using `$.fn.myPlugin.defaults` (plural), in two other places you're using `$.fn.myPlugin.default` (singular).
2. Your code creating the `$.fn.myPlugin.default` object is *inside* your plugin function (and *after* your code trying to use it).

It's #2 that's causing the specific error you're getting, because when you go to use the plugin, this line tries to use something that doesn't exist:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.default.foreground = "blue";
```

You should be creating the `defaults`/`default` object **once**, outside the plugin function, when setting up the plugin.

Something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);
        // ...do the plugin's work here, typically inside a `this.each(/*...*/);` callback, and return `this`
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        foreground: "red",
        background: "green"
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then using it, don't write to `defaults`, pass in options:

```
$(".testDemo").myPlugin({foreground: "blue"});
```

Live Example:

```js
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaults, options);
        // ...do the plugin's work here, typically inside a `this.each(/*...*/);` callback, and return `this`
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).css({
                color: settings.foreground,
                backgroundColor: settings.background
            });
        });
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
        foreground: "red",
        background: "green"
    };
}(jQuery));

$(".testDemo").myPlugin({
    foreground: "blue",
    background: "#ddd"
});
```

```html
<div class="testDemo">This is a .testDemo element</div>
<div class="testDemo">This is another .testDemo element</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Would there not be a scope issue too outside the IIFE?

Comment: @mplungjan - Not if `$` = `jQuery` outside the IIFE (as it usually, but not always, does), no. What is it that seems out of scope?

Comment: @max - Works for me, I added a live example to the answer.

Comment: yes you are right finally the code is working thanks a lot...